# Exporting ROS Master URI from shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ros

I am trying to export ROS_MASTER_URI from a shell script and then launch roscore. In my .sh file I have:

```
roxterm --tab -e $SHELL -c "cd $CATKIN_WS; $srcdevel; export ROS_MASTER_URI='http://locahost:1234'; roscore -p 1234"
```

When I do this, however, I get the following error in the roscore tab:

```
WARNING: ROS_MASTER_URI [http://locahost:1234] host is not set to this machine.
```

When I echo the ROS_MASTER_URI in this tab, it says that it is localhost:1234, which is correct. When I manually execute these commands, it works correctly and roscore launches without any issues. I am not sure why it does not work when launched from a bash file.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a typo- missed the l in localhost. All working now.